# Getting MAC addresses from systems

Tags: python

I have written code to get all the MAC addresses in from systems having multiple MAC addresses and I think there's something which needs to be corrected albeit the code runs fine.

Note: I have just tested it on Android.

```
import re

def getMacs():
    macs = []
    file = os.popen("getmac").read()
    file = file.split("\n")

    for line in file:
        found = re.search(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})', line, re.I)
        if found:
            mac = found.group().replace('-', ':')
            macs.append(mac)

    return macs
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that I think could be improved.

### Include all required imports

The code uses `os.popen()` but doesn't import `os`.  It should.

### Consider other platforms

On my Linux machine, there is no `getmac` command, but one could get the required information via `ifconfig`.  Consider either passing the command in to the function or making OS-specific versions.

### Don't use deprecated functions

The `os.popen()` command is deprecated since version 2.6.  Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead.